# fillna(0) only for specific columns without naming each of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I'm trying to use pandas fillna() on specific columns. The problem is, I don't want to name all these columns. I have one DF, let's call it df_abc, and another one df_123.

df_abc has the columns

**A | B | C**

x | y | z

k | w | k

df_123 has the columns

**1 | 2 | 3**

e | e | z

now I'm merging these the way I want and the result is:

**A | B | C | 1 | 2 | 3**

x | y | z |nan|nan|nan

k | w | k | e | e | z

Now I want use fillna() to fill the columns 1, 2, 3 with 0. I tried:

```
columns = list(df_123.columns.values)
self.df_result[columns] = self.df_result[columns].fillna(0)
```

It gives me

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

I think there has to be a way to fill these columns in a clean way.

Comment: This looks like it should work. What is `self`?

Comment: Although `columns = df_123.columns` should work just as well...

Comment: Do you have duplicate column names maybe?

Comment: self is a class, what exactly do you want to know? I'm merging left on a column and right on index. So these have the same name.

Comment: I was wondering if having the dataframe in a class could interfere with pandas column assignment. As I said this should work. And no duplicate column names?

Comment: Oh my fault there were two columns having the same name. Thanks, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slicing to do that incase you dont want to fill the nan for first three columns i.e

```
df.iloc[:,3:] = df.iloc[:,3:].fillna(0)
```

Comment: `self.df_result.iloc[:, -len(df_123.columns):] = self.df_result.iloc[:, -len(df_123.columns):].fillna(0)`